# Google Map One Infobox Open

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am building a directory, in this example it's a directory for doctors. I created a javascript array called "locations". The visitor can check checkboxes on the map to choose which kind of doctor should be displayed.

This is a sample of the array of locations to loop through in a for loop

```
var locations = [
    [0, 'Total Care', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'Lake Elsinore', '92530', 'CA', 33.6603, -117.3830, '(951) 674-8779', 1],
    ... etc
    ];
```

This explains each key

```
locations[i][0] = business claimed or not (0 = unclaimed and 1 is claimed)  
locations[i][1] = name  
locations[i][2] = if general practitioner = 1, else = 0  
locations[i][3] = if surgeon = 1, else = 0  
locations[i][4] = if cardiologist = 1, else = 0  
locations[i][5] = if urologist = 1, else = 0    
locations[i][6] = if gynecologist = 1, else = 0  
locations[i][7] = if pulmonologist = 1, else = 0  
locations[i][8] = city  
locations[i][9] = zip code  
locations[i][10] = state  
locations[i][11] = latitude  
locations[i][12] = longitude  
locations[i][13] = phone number  
locations[i][14] = z-index
```

All works fine. I have a search function so the visitor can search by name. In the google map code below, I want to find a way to have the infoBox open on the marker of the doctor that was entered in the search function e.g.
if (locations[i][1] == "doctor name"){
code here }

I have been trying to find a solution for the past three days and can't find it, so I would really appreciate some help. This is the Google Map code:

```
var infoBox = null;  
function initialize()  
    {  
    var centerMap = new google.maps.LatLng(33.6603, -117.3830);  
    var mapOptions = {zoom: 11,center: centerMap,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP}  
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), mapOptions);  
    setMarkers(map, locations);  
    }

function setMarkers(map, markers)  
    {  
    var image = {url: 'images/marker.png',size: new google.maps.Size(17, 23),origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),anchor: new google.maps.Point(8, 23)};  
    gpr = $('#check1').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0; // general practitioner  
    srg = $('#check2').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0; // surgeon  
    car = $('#check3').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0; // cardiologist  
    uro = $('#check4').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0; // urologist  
    gyn = $('#check5').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0; // gynecologist  
    pul = $('#check6').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0; // pulmonologist

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i ++)  
        {  
        var locations = markers[i];  
        var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[11], locations[12]);  
        var boxText = document.createElement('div');  
        boxText.style.cssText = 'some styling';  
        link = locations[1].replace(' ','_');
        link = link.toLowerCase();  

        // find out if this genre of doctor was searched for  
        setMarker = 0;  
        if (gpr == 1){if (locations[2] == 1){setMarker = 1;}}  
        if (srg == 1){if (locations[3] == 1){setMarker = 1;}}  
        if (car == 1){if (locations[4] == 1){setMarker = 1;}}  
        if (uro == 1){if (locations[5] == 1){setMarker = 1;}}  
        if (gyn == 1){if (locations[6] == 1){setMarker = 1;}}  
        if (pul == 1){if (locations[7] == 1){setMarker = 1;}}  

        // if one of the checkboxes was checked  
        if (setMarker == 1)  
            {
            if (locations[0])
                {  
                boxText.innerHTML = 'some html with link'; // claimed business  
                }  
            else  
                {  
                boxText.innerHTML = 'some html without link'; // unclaimed business  
                }  
            var infoBoxOptions = {content: boxText,disableAutoPan: false,maxWidth: 0,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(5, -80),zIndex: locations[14],boxStyle: {background: "url('images/tip.png') no-repeat",opacity: 0.9,width: "405px",height: "75px",border: '0px solid #900'},closeBoxMargin: "13px 5px 5px 5px",closeBoxURL: "images/close.gif",infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),isHidden: false,pane: "floatPane",enableEventPropagation: false};
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: siteLatLng,map: map,title: locations[1],zIndex: locations[14],icon: image,html: boxText});  
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (e) {infoBox.setContent(this.html);infoBox.open(map, this);});  
            var infoBox = new InfoBox(infoBoxOptions);  
            }  
        }  
    }
```

Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the console for any JS errors? In addition, as per your debugging, what part of the is actually not working - Is it the click, variable initialization... etc?

Comment: Everything is working Gautam Bhutani. I want to have the InfoBox open by default "only" on the marker of the doctor's name/clinic that was entered in the search function, while all other InfoBoxes are only displayed when the corresponding marker is clicked (which is already working). Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, you can just loop through your markers until the title matches the search text, and then open the appropriate info box on that marker. Something like:

```
$('#searchButton').click(function() {
    var searchText = $('#searchBox').val();
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        if (markers[i].title.indexOf(searchText) > -1)
            infoBoxes[i].open(map, markers[i]);
    }
});
```

This example assumes you have two existing parallel arrays of markers and their corresponding info boxes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Josh. Opening the InfoBox is not the problem, it's setting all the markers on the Google Map where all the InfoBoxes are hidden and only show when the corresponding marker is clicked, while "only one" InfoBox is open, the InfoBox corresponding with the name of the doctor/clinic that was entered in the search fucntion.

Comment: Hi rahulroy. I can't remember. It's been more than a year ago. Sorry I could not help.